# .NET 3.5 missing from the ASP.NET drop down in IIS after new install

Tags: .net, asp.net, iis

I have just installed the .NET 3.5 Framework to my Windows 2003 server and when I try to create a new website I can't select 3.5 from the web site properties ASP.NET tab in IIS.

This works fine with 1.0, 1.1, and 2.0.

I know the framework install process was completely different with 3.5, but I assume it should be available in the drop down.

What can I do to solve this problem?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

That's because ASP.NET 3.5 still uses the CLR from 2.0. The CLR hasn't changed in 3.5, it's more an extension to 2.0. (I hope I say this correct)

So while you cannot choose 3.5, you **can** run webapplications written in 3.5.

Comment: Rick Strahl has a nice article on his blog about this: http://www.west-wind.com/Weblog/posts/289139.aspx

Answer (score 7):

The .NET Framework v3.5 is essentially a "feature enhancement" on top of the 2.0 core. It has been this way since version 2.0 came out. You won't see a new version in IIS until they do a fundamental core shift, or something major along those lines to warrant having your ASP.NET sites to be configured as such.

But don't worry, your .NET 3.5 apps will run just fine under the 2.0 configuration listing. You'll notice that there will be redirects in your web.config file to point to the 3.5 files for some of the updated libraries.

Answer (score 3):

This may answer your question:

http://blogs.msdn.com/vijaysk/archive/2008/03/20/running-asp-net-3-5-on-iis.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Set it as 2.0. 3.5 runs effectively as a set of extensions to 2.0.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's supposed to show up. 3.5 is basically a 2.0 app that has the 3.5 extensions included via the web.config. Choose 2.0

Answer (score 1):

There is no 3.5 option. You're still running on top of the 2.0 framework. It is running correctly.

Answer (score 1):

ASP.NET is still in version 2.0, but it will run on the .NET 3.5 libraries. It is confusing, but alas.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot find 3.5 on IIS, you'll find 2.0.
But, if you want to be sure that the install went well, go to

```
%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework
```

(which is C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework   on most systems)

and look for a folder named 3.5.